# Keras ImageDataGenerator equivalent for csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have a bunch of data ordered in folders like in the following picture:

[image]

I need to build a DataIterator in order to fit the data in a Neural Network model. I have found many examples to solve this problem when the data are images, using the Keras class *ImageDataGenerator* and its method *flow_from_directory*, but not when the data is a csv structure.

Each csv file is a 512x11 float array that represents the power adquired by a sensor. I thought about transforming each of these CSVs to an image format and then applying the *ImageDataGenerator* class, but the compression will result in loss of information (in an image each value is represented by a 8 bits integer, while my data is a 32bits float).

So, there is an equivalent in Keras to *ImageDataGenerator* to load csv files instead of images?

Comment: You should create your own generator. You can derive from a `keras.utils.Sequence`, for instance. You will need to find the files, load and get rows manually inside this generator.

Comment: @Ignacio Hey, have you managed to create a code for passing .npy files to ImageDataGenerator? If so, would you share your code here? Thanks

Comment: @NeStack no, I just used the code below to generate a class that accepts csv. I guess you can change the READ_CSV_FUNCTION to read your files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write your own generator by subclassing the `Sequence` object. The idea is that you compose some kind of dataframe (a pandas dataframe, for instance) with two columns: one column for the labels and on with paths to your csv files. Your datagenerator will use this file to determine the length of the dataset (number of csv files) and to read files in batches and pass them to the model.

Your code could look something like this:

```
class DataSequence(Sequence):
    """
    Keras Sequence object to train a model on a list of csv files
    """
    def __init__(self, df, batch_size, mode='train'):
        """
        df = dataframe with two columns: the labels and a list of filenames
        """
        self.df = df
        self.bsz = batch_size
        self.mode = mode

        # Take labels and a list of image locations in memory
        self.labels = self.df['label'].values
        self.file_list = self.df['file_names']

    def __len__(self):
        return int(math.ceil(len(self.df) / float(self.bsz)))

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.indexes = range(len(self.im_list))
        if self.mode == 'train':
            # Shuffles indexes after each epoch if in training mode
            self.indexes = random.sample(self.indexes, k=len(self.indexes))

    def get_batch_labels(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of labels
        return self.labels[idx * self.bsz: (idx + 1) * self.bsz]

    def get_batch_features(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of inputs
        return np.array([READ_CSV_FUNCTION(f) for f in self.file_list[idx * self.bsz: (1 + idx) * self.bsz]])

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.get_batch_features(idx)
        batch_y = self.get_batch_labels(idx)
        return batch_x, batch_y
```

You would just need to replace `READ_CSV_FUNCTION` with your function of choice to read and parse the csv files.

Comment: If I understood correctly READ_CSV_FUNCTION(im) should return the content of the csv file in a vector, right? Not in the original matrix form. Something like pd.read_csv(im).values.flatten()

Comment: It depends on how you want to feed it to your model. If your first layer is a dense layer, then you want it as a vector, yes. For a convolutional layer that would be a matrix.

Comment: I tried with a simple model and when I have tried to fit the data I get the next error in the keras engine: 'DataSequence' object has no attribute 'ndim'... Should I create that attribute in the DataSequence you have proposed?

Comment: Are you using it with model.fit_generator()? Check https://github.com/sdcubber/Keras-Sequence-boilerplate/blob/master/Keras-Sequence.ipynb for a complete example with images