# Is there a way to increase the size of the dataset with labels using data augmentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement logistic regression on Kaggle's digit recognition [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data?select=train.csv). There are 42000 rows in the train set and I want to increase the count using data augmentation.

I tried using keras's `ImageDataGenerator` object

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(  
        rotation_range=30,   
        zoom_range = 0.2,  
        width_shift_range=0.2,         
        height_shift_range=0.2)

datagen.fit(X_train)
```

but the size remains same, I later found out that `ImageDataGenerator` does not actually add rows but inserts augmented data during training.
Is there any other tool to save or increase the data with same labels ?

Comment: What do you mean the size remains the same? Could you show your full code? You might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634924/keras-imagedatagenerator-equivalent-for-csv-files) instead.

Comment: The dataset shape initially was (42000, 784) and after running the above script it remains the same. I thought it will grow 4X like (168000, 784), I read that keras creates data real time while training

Comment: It remains the same unless you choose to save the augmentations somewhere else. I however am not sure it will work on CSV data(see link above).

Comment: @NelsonGon, yea about that I did infact reshape the csv rows to 4D array of shape (-1, 28, 28, 1) and the function runs without any errors, so would I be able to save the augmented data along with labels ? That would be great

Comment: @NelsonGon, thanks for the input I was able to save the augmented data to an array, I will post the answer soon, once I save them with labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I eventually saved the augmented data with labels. I sampled 5 rows for viewing pleasure. And the `for` loop might not be the best way to write to array when full dataset is considered

```
#importing data
train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
X_train = train.drop(labels=["label"], axis=1)
y_train = train.label

#sampling 5 rows and reshaping x to 4D array
x = X_train[0:5].values.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
y = y_train[0:5]

#Augmentation parameters
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(  
        rotation_range=30,   
        zoom_range = 0.2,  
        width_shift_range=0.2,  
        height_shift_range=0.2,  
        )  

#using .flow instead of .fit to write to an array
augmented_data = []
num_augmented = 0
batch = 5  # for 5*5 = 25 entries
for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(X_2, y, batch_size=batch, shuffle=False,):
    augmented_data.append(X_batch)
    augmented_labels.append(y_batch)
    num_augmented += 1
    if num_augmented == x.shape[0]:
        break
augmented_data = np.concatenate(augmented_data) #final shape = (25,28,28,1)
augmented_labels = np.concatenate(augmented_labels)


#Lets take a look at augmented images
for index, image in enumerate(augmented_data):
    plt.subplot(5, 5, index + 1)
    plt.imshow(np.reshape(image, (28,28)), cmap=plt.cm.gray)


# reshaping and converting to df
augmented_data_reshaped = augmented_data.reshape(25, 784)
augmented_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(augmented_data_reshaped)
# inserting labels in df
augmented_dataframe.insert(0, "label", augmented_labels)
header = list(train.columns.values)
augmented_dataframe.columns = header
# write
augmented_dataframe.to_csv("augmented.csv")
```

[image: Augmented digits data]